# Adyen custom card tab navigation is not working properly in latest version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, adyen

I am using adyen sdk 3.13.0 to render custom card component. My issue is I couldn't navigate to next inputfield from credit card input field by single tab key press. I need to press tab key 3 times to navigate from credit card field. But this issue is not present in any other fields like expiry or cvv. I could see two extra input fields in creditcard number iframe. This won't be present in older vesion of sdk.

I have checked the same in version 3.3.0 and it is working perfectly fine

Comment: Those two fields have a tabindex of -1 so they should be skipped. What browser and browser version are you using?

Comment: @luke_b I am using chrome 83 in ubuntu

Comment: The tabbing works correctly with chrome 86 in ubuntu. Can you inspect the element and ensure they have the tabindex of -1.

Comment: do you still see this problem when using chrome 86?

Comment: @luke_b I have checked this on chrome 86. I stll have this issue. I couldn't find tabIndex atribute on those input fields

Answer (score 2):

The two extra input fields that you describe have been added in order to help with credit card auto-completion. They get a tabIndex of -1 so as not interfere with the tabbing process.
Sadly, in one scenario, Chrome on iOS, we cannot set this tabIndex attribute because otherwise the auto-completion will not happen (!?)
However it would seem that this (no tabIndex attribute) is now also happening in your use-case (Chrome on Ubuntu).
We will look further into this - and try to find some way to reproduce the issue (we don't work on Linux machines). I suggest you contact [Adyen support](https://www.adyen.help/hc/en-us) in order to make a ticket for this issue and get it registered in our system